# How to get Python to perform keystrokes in CMD

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cmd

I am attempting to build a program that can execute multiple commands within CMD from the same window.

```
import os
os.system('python.exe & cmd.exe')
```

I understand there are more efficient ways for this to be accomplished, but  for the sake of my situation it should be accepted.
The program must start with python.exe because this is the only way to access CMD without it being prevented by the administrator account.

I require python to execute keyboard commands so as it can continue on in CMD, as the only way I can reach the command prompt stage is to stop the python.exe via 'ctrl c.'

```
os.system('python.exe (ctrl c) & cmd.exe')
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you realize that `system('python.exe & cmd.exe')` executes as `cmd.exe /c "python.exe & cmd.exe"`? So you're running CMD to run CMD. Why don't you simply try `subprocess.call('cmd.exe')`? Or if you want it attached to a new console, use `subprocess.call('cmd.exe', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`.

Comment: I have used python.exe as that is the only work around I know to get passed administrative blocks. I don't know whether subprocess.call would do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must download the pyautogui module.

> import pyautogui
>
> ```
> pyautogui.typewriter('[keyboard     command'])
> ```